# React - returns undefined after setState

Tags: reactjs

I have the below piece of code in project. I wonder how come the data become undefined after the setState. I could see all the 'item' data while debugging it. But in the next statement it becomes undefined.

```
    let result = this._DataAccessObj.getRequestData(this.props.listId,this.props.itemId).then((item:IRequest) =>{
        this.setState ({
        Title: item.Title,
        Id: item.Id,
        RequestorId:item.RequestorId,  //here i could see the data
        Created: item.Created
        });
   });
   console.log(this.state.RequestorId);  //it is always logging undefined
```

May i know how to get the exact requestorId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this, It might help: [here](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b#:%7E:text=setState%20function%2C%20which%20will%20accept,generally%20lead%20to%20state%20inconsistency.).

```
this.setState ({
    Title: item.Title,
    Id: item.Id,
    RequestorId:item.RequestorId,  //here i could see the data
    Created: item.Created
    }, () => {
          console.log(this.state); //here you will get all details 
});
```

This happens because `setState` works in an asynchronous way. You can't see the updated state by consoling it just after the `this.setState` call.

Comment: Kudos. It helped me!